# How to refresh JW player for Live streaming?

Tags: jquery, refresh, jwplayer

Currently user refreshes the entire web page when ever the stream get struck. This adds load to web server as the page has to be served again.

Instead, I want the user to click a button "Refresh Stream" so that JW player reloads/refreshes again with the same live and doesn't refresh the entire page

I want through JS API but I am not sure what JW player event to trigger on "Refresh Stream" button click.

Comment: you can reload playlist like this:`jwplayer().load([{file:"myasset.mp4"}]);` and make sure to set autostart to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, make a link on your page like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jwplayer().load('my_stream.m3u8');jwplayer().play();>Refresh Stream</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question, I know. But the accepted solution did not help me when I ran into the same issue as the OP did. The answer Max provided is better. This is how I did it, however:

```
this.player = jwplayer("...").setup(...);
let player_url = ... /* data from backend */

...

this.player.on('buffer', function() {
    debounce = setTimeout(function () {
        this.player.load([{file:player_url}]);
        this.player.play();
    }.bind(this), 10000);
}.bind(this));
```

This way, whatever goes wrong, and the player tries to reconnect it will refresh itself every 10 seconds without the user doing anything to it. While the provided file url is correct, it won't throw an error.

This is for refreshing live streams only. (I don't know why you would deal with this in case of a VOD anyway)

Edit: the reason the accepted answer didn't help me was because the load function isn't okay with just the file name but rather an object in an array